# How to access a row from a panda dataframe using index without column header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

e.g -

```
df= A   B    C
    1    2   3
    2    4   5
    2    1   3
```

I want to access second row without header

If I do `df.iloc[[1]]` it is giving me -

```
         A   B   C
         2   4   5
```

as output, but I want

`2 4 5`

as output. No column header is needed and eventually I will store that in list.

Comment: `df.iloc[1].values`

Comment: `I will store that in list.` -  Do you think  values `2, 4 ,5` ? Like `df.iloc[1].tolist()` ?

Comment: Or is necessary save DataFrame with no header to csv like `df.iloc[[1]].to_csv(file, header=None, index=False)` ?

Comment: I will take 2,4,5 and eventually store in a list..which will be looked like ['2','4','5']

Comment: hmmm, so need join it by space like `' '.join(df.iloc[1].tolist())` ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

use `list_ob = list(df.iloc[1])` and use list_ob, it will return desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try this below snippets to get different types of results as you wish,

```
print df.iloc[1].values #<type 'numpy.ndarray'> [2 4 5]
print df.iloc[1].values.tolist() #<type 'list'> [2, 4, 5]
print ' '.join(map(str,df.iloc[1].values.tolist())) #<type 'str'> 2 4 5
```